# Ntfs on freebsd not working, other solution

Tags: windows, filesystems, freebsd

I am using FreeBSD 10. I want to share an external hdd formatted in ntfs with both FeeBSD and Windows.

Fusefs-ntfs is refusing to cooperate, so I can't manage to mount ntfs disk to FreeBSD, though I did manage to mount fat32 formatted disk (but the limitation of 4 GB is holding me back).

What file system can I use on both FreeBSD with easy mount rw, and on Windows with rw too?

Answer (score 0):

Getting fuse-ntfs to work is still your best option. Windows doesn't really support reading other than native file-systems.

There are different tools (e.g. [ufs2tools](http://ufs2tools.sourceforge.net/)) that give read access to UFS2 filesystems on Windows. But none of them support writing AFAIK.